# React Native Calendar picker giving null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using [react-native-calendar-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-picker)
The issue is:-
When I am selecting for the first time it is giving correct date for both startDate and endDate.
But after first time startDate is giving null.
My component code is:-

```
<CalendarPicker 
 startFromMonday={true} 
 allowRangeSelection={true} 
  onDateChange={onDateChange} 
 />
```

my state code is:-

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
 startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  })
```

My function is:-

```
 const onDateChange = (date, type) => {
    console.log("changed date", moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    if (type === 'END_DATE') {
        setState({
            ...state,
            endDate: date,
        });
    } else {
        setState({
            ...state,
            startDate: date,
            endDate: null,
        });
    }
}
```

[image: issue image]

[video while reproducing issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GSCuK0BvvmVcuFz1D6eQS72EZ--0T728/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, since I don't see the complete code. Please try using a function to setState so that you are guaranteed you get the previous state prior to setting the new state. React processed setStates in batches. I am not sure if the issue lies here but try this else we may look at other options

```
const onDateChange = (date, type) => {
  console.log("changed date", moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
  if (type === "END_DATE") {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, endDate: date };
    });
  } else {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        startDate: date,
        endDate: null,
      };
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: It is not an issue with state. The issue is calendar is giving null value on `onchange`

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam thanks for clarifying QQ - is your endDate coming out at null or both start and end dates are rendering as null onDataChage? I my thinking is right only your endDate should be null onDateChange

Comment: only start date is coming null, from second time.

Comment: okay pls try this `import React, { useState } from "react";
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
const onDateChange = (date, type) => {
  console.log("changed date", moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
  if (type === "END_DATE") {
    setEndDate(date);
  } else {
    setStartDate(date);
  }
};`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting wrong somewhere when setState. I have created a working snack demo for you, please check if this solves your problem.

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@saad-bashar/calendarpicker) is the snack link.

Comment: Please select both the date for the first time (it is working fine). And again select the start date without refreshing the page, it is showing blank in snack.

Comment: It is not showing blank for me. When I select a date I always get to see the selected date in the output. Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Look I am attaching a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Did you check the image?

Comment: Can you share the snack link with me where you are facing this issue?

Comment: video is of your snack.

Comment: But my snack is using a functional component. 

https://snack.expo.io/@saad-bashar/calendarpicker